# Should there be swear filters on SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I just came across an inappropriate answer, and I'm wondering why the post was even allowed. The poster directly infringes copyright (by copying someone else's answer) and swears three times. Why are there no swear filters on SO? The rules explicitly say:

> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

Shouldn't these types of answers be automatically rejected or automatically sent to low quality post review?

Comment: Word filters are problematic. One clbuttic example is ... well, clbuttic. Or the fact that we filter the word "problem" out of titles, with all the "issues" that results in. And then there are legitimate posts **about** word filters that might need the occasional example. In general such filters seem to make a lot of sense, until you see all the edge-cases that pop up when you actually implement them. If you see such terrible abuse however, feel free to edit it out, and flag for moderator attention pointing at the original revision.

Comment: @Bart: Are you sure you didn't mean clbuttic? It's spelled clbuttic.

Comment: If I meant clbuttic I would have written clbuttic @BoltClock. Clbuttic is what I meant, so that is what I wrote.

Comment: @Bart: I rest my case.

Comment: We all know that fully automated word filters are problematic, but I sure would hope that a post containing the phrase "cunt nigger" would at least get automatically sent to the Low Quality review queue.

Comment: No argument there @68cherries. Point is, such filters are problematic. A dump into the VLQ queue like Ilmari suggests (if that doesn't happen already) would be far better IMO.

Comment: Let's not [do that one again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive) shall we @roippi ;)

Comment: what the #&$^ makes you %*(&^ing think there is no god ($&% swear filter on this *%^&^ing site?

Comment: Every time someone brings this up, I point them to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/922184 There are totally valid reasons to use profanity in posts.

Comment: Is WTF considered swearing?

Comment: You assume that the Phukwits prone to swearing are literate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Automatic detection of profanity has had a long and very anti-illustrious history in computing; one fabled (possibly even apocryphal) example was where no emails could be sent by anyone in Scunthorpe district council due to the swear-filter picking up on the mandatory signature on everyone's message including the name of their employer (and the messages sent back about why the block was happening were *also* being blocked by the same rule). The key problems are that the set of words that are offensive are ever-changing and *highly* context dependent; computers are still pretty much terrible at sensitivity to such things.

So we're definitely going to have to have humans in the loop. These days, that's the review queues (and yes, it would be the Very Low Quality queue; there are very few points that it is necessary to add profanity to make; one of the hallmarks of profanity is its gratuitousness). It's not as quick as automatic detection, but it's *much* more certain to get it right. We could have a list that causes automatic enqueueing, but we should not neglect the fact that people can use flagging as well; we already have “offensive” as one of the official acceptable reasons for a flag. No change needed.

---

My take? Found it? Flag it. Move on.

Comment: Software for rude word detection has been linked to much character buttbuttination of otherwise-innocent words, all richardtated by humourless fools who can't write a good Regular Expression…

Comment: Correct. That said, there are some filters that make the human flagging action act somewhat more quickly.

Comment: The real answer to "Why there is no swear filter" is that current technology doesn't allow us to build a swear filter. We need a bot as intelligent as a human to do that.