# Cannot point out that what the OP is doing is rep whoring

Tags: discussion, word-filter

There was that question where the OP meant it to be self-answered, but demanded 10 upvotes before they would post the solution.

I wanted to point out to the OP that this behaviour is called [rep whoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151320/147640) and is not welcome, and that if they have a solution, they should just post it.

However I was not able to post my comment because apparently the word "whoring" is not allowed to appear in a comment. I kept getting the big red popup:

[image]

I thought we did not not have [swear filters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256074/11683), apparently we do?
Can we not have them / make them more relaxed?

Comment: Technically I doubt if that OP was *rep wh___ing*. They were more or less taking knowledge as a hostage and demanded rep in exchange to release the hostage. That is in the higher-up the violence range.

Comment: I hate the term "rep whoring". Of all the words in the English language there's got to be a better expression.

Comment: It fits the definitions of a *racket*.  Perhaps "rep racketeering" doesn't roll off the tip of the tongue as easily.

Comment: @HansPassant - I like the alliteration.

Comment: @Flexo: I found a while ago that [`rep-hound`](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/whats-a-less-offensive-substitute-for-rep-whores) sounded much better.

Answer (score 25):

The reason why "rep whoring" is not allowed in comments on the main site is because it's rude, offensive and not constructive. I'd be the first to admit that the OP is bending the rules of the site in this case.

Yes, we all know this sort of behaviour goes on, but the way to counter it is to not vote on these posts. If people stop getting rep for posting then they'll eventually stop posting.

In this case, I'd edit out the commentary and move on. If you think that a moderator's intervention would help, flag the post. We can lock the post if the OP insists on editing the request back in which will prevent them from getting the upvotes (at least for the length of the lock).

Vote if you want to - but do so on the merits (or otherwise) of the question.

If you know the answer yourself, post it. This will reduce even further the incentive for the user to hold back their answer.

In summary - use (or rather don't use!) the tools available to you. There's no need to add (even more) drama to the site by adding potentially inflammatory comments. If you want to point the user to a meta post then you still can - but as long as you don't use the blocked words.

Comment: My point is that there is a discussion on Meta about this sort of behaviour (so I assume discussing it is okay), and this behaviour happens to be called "rep whoring". I wanted to point the OP to that discussion so that they learn what it's called and that it's not welcome. I think it's different from saying "you are a rep whore" which would be offensive. The whole pointing and learning thing obviously makes no sense when the OP is well aware of what they are doing and how it's called, but I did not have a strong feeling that was the case.

Comment: `If you want to point the user to a meta post then you still can` - well yes, but still, only if I specifically use the short form of the link. I can post `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151320/147640`, but `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151320/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-rep-whoring` will be blocked even though it's the same thing.